# How to prove to the server that I as a client am logged in with the given uid?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Heres my problem:

I wan't to be able to create new users for my website, from my website. This is only aloud though, if I  have the "isAdmin" flag set to true in the realtime db under `/users/myid`.

Generally I would have done this with a security rule but the problem here is that I need to use the admin SDK, since the normal "createNewUser" method signs in to the newly created user automatically. I as an admin though, want to be able to create a new user and stay logged in as myself. So what I wan't to do is use ajax post request to my server with my uid und the new userdata which is to be created. My server then checks if the given uid has the isAdmin flag and if so creates the user with the firebase admin SDK which provides such a method.

But, anyone, if they have an admins uid, could hit up that request and create a new user. (My clients definetely get uid's from other users).

So how would I go about proving to the server that I am actually logged in with that uid. 
From my understanding, tokens are used to be able to write to the database, but I don't need that permission, I just need to prove that I'm actually logged in with that uid. 
Is there something I'm missing? Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was easier then I thought. This will generate a token on the client side:

```
 firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(true).then(function(token) {
        // send request to server with generated token
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
    });
```

Which I can then verify on the server like so:

```
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {
    var uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // user is logged in 
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // user is not logged in, or other error occured
  });
```

Taken from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens